# Transform the array into a string

Tags: php

So i'm calling the Coinbase API.

```
<?php

$ctx = stream_context_create(["http"=>["user_agent"=>"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0"]]);
$coinbase_coins = file_get_contents('https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/spot?currency=USD', true, $ctx);
$coinbase_coins = json_decode($coinbase_coins, true);

print_r($coinbase_coins);

?>
```

it returns the array

`Array ( [data] => Array ( [base] => BTC [currency] => USD [amount] => 15715.2 ) )`

however i just wants the `15715.2` so i can put it in a `<span>`.

What do I need to do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is an array inside an array. Please try

```
$amount = $coinbase_coins['data']['amount'];
```

The `$amount` variable will now have `15715.2`